# SharePoint CAML query - to retrieve column value with certain pattern from Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, caml

I need to query from pages library to get a HTML column.
This column contains rich text and references to various URLs(anchor tag). 
The query should return items which contain a column value with hyperlink to  certain URL Pattern.

For ex: Column contains `"http://example.com/my-sites/......[UniqueIDWhichVaries].aspx"`

Below is my caml query:

```
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='MyColumn' />
   </ViewFields>
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='MyColumn' />
         <Value Type='HTML'>a href=http://example.com/my-sites/</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Where>
   <QueryOptions>
      <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
   </QueryOptions>
```

This query does not return expected results.

I would like to know what is the best way to retrieve such items. I need to use this query in a power shell script.

Can anyone help me here, please?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

To put this in powershell you can use the following reference:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-do-a-CAML-Query-6f5260cf

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below query:

```
<ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='MyColumn' />
   </ViewFields>
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='MyColumn' />
         <Value Type='Note'>http://example.com/my-sites/......[UniqueIDWhichVaries].aspx</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Where>
   <QueryOptions>
      <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
   </QueryOptions>
```

You can encode the square brackets using their unicode value in query:

```
http://example.com/my-sites/......&#91;UniqueIDWhichVaries&#93;.aspx
```

Hope this will help you!